# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'speech_recognition' windows

Tags: python, windows, pip

i installed the module but it's still not recognized in terminal what could i do?
thats my code

```
import speech_recognition as sr

listener = sr.Recognizer()
try:
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print('listening...')
        voice = listener.listen(source)
        command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
        print(command)
except:
    pass
```

Comment: did you install it in the same environment you're running the python file from?

Comment: how can i verify?

Comment: Use `pip freeze` in a terminal to see a list of all installed modules.